# Various definitions of Supremum stated formally

Tags: definition, supremum-and-infimum

In literature, I found 4 different definitions for Supremum. I tried to express these formally.

1. Question: Are these definitions correct?
2. Question: How can we prove their equivalence formally?
3. Question: Are there even more definitions than these 4?
4. Question: To definition (3), do I have to write both, that $\epsilon$ is an element of $\Bbb{F}$ and $>0$, and - if yes - how?
5. Question: To definition (4), what if Supremum doesn't exist?

Let $\Bbb{F}$ be an ordered field.
Let $A \subset \Bbb{F}$ be nonempty.
Let $s \in \Bbb{F}$.

(1) $s=\sup A$ $:\iff (\forall a \in A(a \le s)) \land ( \forall b \in \Bbb{F}((\forall a \in A(a \le b)) \implies (s \le b) ))$

(2) $s=\sup A$ $:\iff (\forall a \in A(a \le s)) \land (\forall b \in \Bbb{F} ( (b < s) \implies \exists a \in A (a > b)))$

(3) $s=\sup A$ $:\iff (\forall a \in A(a \le s)) \land (\forall \epsilon > 0(\exists a \in A(a > s-\epsilon)) )$

(4) $s=\sup A$ $:\iff s=min\{c \in \Bbb{F} | (\forall a \in A(a \le c)\}$

Comment: I think you want to add an $s = $ to the right hand side of definition 4

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**: Yes these definitions are correct

**Question 2**: Seeing that definitions 1 and 2 is equivalent is easy. Notice that both start by saying “$s$ is an upper bound for $A$”. Then the definitions split as follows:

1. For any other upper bound $b$, we have that $s \leq b$
2. If $b$ is smaller than $s$, then $b$ is not an upper bound for $A$

Notice that (2) is the contrapositive of (1). Thus they are equivalent.

Definition 3 also starts by asserting that $s$ is an upper bound for $A$, but then goes on to say that for every $\epsilon > 0$, we may find an element $a \in A$ such that $s - \epsilon < a$. This is easily seen to be equivalent to condition (2) above.

Finally definition 4 is seen to be equivalent to definition 1.

**Question 3**: Sure, we could come up with all kinds of different equivalent conditions.

**Question 4**: I’m not sure what you mean.

**Question 5**: Suppose that $A$ is bounded above, but fails to have a supremum (for example, the set $\{x \in \mathbb{Q} : x^2 < 2 \}$). Then let’s look at the set $\{x \in \mathbb{F} : \text{ for all } a \in A, a \leq x\}$. Since $A$ has no supremum, this set will fail to have a smallest element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time and answering.

Comment: To Q1: Isn't it strange that one can only find Supremum definitions in natural language?
To Q2: Yes true, (1) iff (2) because of contraposition. (2) iff (3) is clear intuitively, but I really wonder which rules (is it first-order logic rules?) can "convert" (2) into (3)... and (1) into (4)?
To Q4: What I mean is that, formally, it's not clear that epsilon is an element of F right? In order to be formally correct, don't we have to specify the set to which epsilon belongs? If yes: how?

Comment: We use natural language because we’re people! As much as I love mathematical logic, logical formulae are not easy to read. These proofs could be written formally through the deduction rules of first order logic, but that would be extremely long and much less clear than a natural language explanation.

As for $\epsilon$, it must be in the ordered field $\mathbb{F}$. The quantifiers you wrote are quantifying over elements of structure you’re working in. This is one of the defining characteristics of first order logic.